# How do I auto-authenticate from Ubuntu into a Windows partition?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm currently using Ubuntu Karmic and my mp3s are located on a Windows partition.  Each time I reboot my computer, I have to manually authenticate into the Windows partition to get access to my songs.  Is there a way to auto-authenticate into the Windows partition of my choice when Ubuntu starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the partition in /etc/fstab 
Then it will always be mounted when the system boots.

To help get the format of the entry you can do a cat /etc/mtab from a terminal before and after you 'authenticate' which is really just mounting the partition. Look for the line that is added about your windows partition and put something similar into the /etc/fstab.

Comment: I found this guide helpful: http://mesanna.com/2009/02/02/how-to-mount-a-partition-automatically-in-ubuntu-linux/